# Jquery selector loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change width of the divs. But $(div#i) is not true. How can i do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var things = new Array();
        things[0] = 13; things[1] = 26; things[2] = 39;

    for(var i=0;i<things.length;i++)
            $(div#i).css("width",things[i]*100);
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="0" style=" width: 300px; height:20px; margin-left: 25px; padding-left: 15px; background-color: #900"> </div> <br>
<div id="1" style=" width: 300px; height:20px; margin-left: 25px; padding-left: 15px; background-color: #900"> </div> <br>
<div id="2" style=" width: 300px; height:20px; margin-left: 25px; padding-left: 15px; background-color: #900"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('div#' + i).css(...`

Comment: FYI shortcut; `var things = [13,26,39];`

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Numerics are fine in HTML5 however

Comment: Use a class instead of selecting by numbered IDs. `<div id="0" class="myDivs">...</div>` `$(".myDivs").css("width", function(i) { return things[i] * 100; });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Selectors should be strings, and you don't need the 'div' since ids must be unique. Also, as mentioned in the comments, ids that are strictly numbers are only valid in HTML5, so if you want this to work consistently on old browsers, I would suggest using the `data-index` method I posted below.

```
$('#' + i).css("width",things[i]*100);
```

I'd also use Array literal syntax.

```
var things = [13, 26, 39];
```

On the id uniqueness and compatibility front, I'd really recommend you not use `id` since it isn't really semantically valuable.

Instead of `<div id="..."`, I'd do `<div data-index="..."` and make use of jQuery's automatic collection iteration for `css`.

```
$('[data-index]').css('width', function(){
    return things[$(this).data('index')] * 100);
});
```

However in reality, if you have a one-one relationship between divs and their indexes in the array, you can also do this, and not need any extra attributes in your HTML.

```
$('body > div').css('width', function(i){
  return things[i] * 100;
});
```

Also remember that you will need to wrap all of this in a `ready` callback, which you aren't doing in your example.

Comment: Doing `$('[data-index="' + i + '"]')` in a loop will be horribly expensive, especially in browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll`. ...your update is much better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I"m missing something, you could just do:

```
$('#' + i).css("width",things[i]*100);
```

Because you're calling an ID, which should be unique on the page.